# Cassandra CQL Shell unable to connect

Tags: python, cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0

I installed cassandra in windows 7 ( 64 bits ) , and when i launch the cql shell it says connection error unable to connect to any server , and it close immediately .

[Here is the screen shot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuOuO.png)

Comment: Can you make sure Cassandra is running and if so provide screenshot of it and the error?

Comment: i'm totally newbie in Cassandra , it's my first time with all of this can you specifie what do you mean by " make sure Cassandra is running " how i can now ?

Comment: i add the screenshot

Comment: press ctrl+alt+del & choose task manager in windows and make sure "Cassandra" process is shown in the list running process

Comment: no it's not in the list :/

Comment: yup and thats why you aren't able to connect to it  via CQL :)

Comment: and wha now sir ?

Comment: It depends on how you performed the installation. Here is a step by step link that I found https://www.guru99.com/download-install-cassandra.html#2

Comment: i followed all those steps and doesnt work , i even unistall it 3 time and install it and no changes

Comment: thanks man i solved the problem it was a line in cassandra.yaml it must modified to  " cdc_raw_directory: C:/Program Files/DataStax-DDC/data/cdc_raw " and started the DDC server and it worked like magic